# Make PayPal button permanently disappear on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal

I always find an answer to my questions on stackoverflow when searching the website. This time however it came to the point where I need to ask a question.

Below is a HTML code for a PayPal 'Buy now' button. Pretty basic stuff. Here comes the catch. I want to make it disappear on click for every user (so not just the one who clicked it on his device). Is it possible to do something like this?

Thank you in advance.

edit: There's one more scenario that is more complicated. It is about making the button disappear for everyone once it was not just clicked but after paid for the item this button is linked to. Is PayPal API capable of something like this?

Comment: You could send an ajax call to the server, and set a flag to false in a database. Then, when someone visits the page you can check the flag before serving the HTML. If you really want the button to disappear in real-time from all open pages across the world, you will need a live connection, for example with web sockets.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. This sounds reasonable.There's one more scenario that is more complicated. It is about making the button disappear for everyone once it was not just clicked but after paid for the item this button is linked to. Do you think PayPal would allow something like this?

Comment: You can search the [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/) to see if they offer a way to disable the button once a payment has been made.

Comment: I would add a field to the database something like `paypalPaid:false` which will change to true when you receive callback from paypal. Then let the disabled attribute render according to the `paypalPaid` value. Or you can just delete the button if you want